# Let $\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$ be $n\times n$ complex matrices such that the unital subaglebra generated by $A_i$'s is whole $M_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Let $\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$ be a set of $n\times n$ complex matrices such that the unital subalgebra generated by $A_i$'s is the full algebra $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Let $\Pi_m=\{A_{i_1}A_{i_2}\cdots A_{i_m}:\, 1\le i_1,\ldots,i_m\le k\}$ for each $m\ge 1$ and $\Pi_0=\{I\}$. We know that
$$
\operatorname{span}\left(\,\bigcup_{m=0}^\infty\Pi_m\right)=M_n. 
$$
Is it true that
$$
\operatorname{span}\left(\bigcup_{m=0}^{n-1}\Pi_m\right)=M_n,
$$
i.e. products of at most $n-1$ many elements are enough to span whole $M_n$?

The examples, I'm looking at, where the answer to the above question is yes. Although I'm not able to prove it. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=2$, consider the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$.  These generate the whole matrix algebra but there are only three products of at most one of them so they do not span the whole algebra.

There are similar examples for every $n>1$: the matrices $e_{i(i+1)}$ whose only nonzero entry is a $1$ in the $(i,i+1)$ entry (taken mod $n$) generate the whole matrix algebra, but any product of at most $n-1$ of them (besides the empty product) has all diagonal entries equal to $0$.